# How do IaaS nodes communicate to form a cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, akka, iaas

How do nodes communicate with each other, or how do they become aware of each other (in a decentralized manner) in an IaaS environment? As an example: [this article about Akka on Google's IaaS](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/01/large-akka-cluster-on-google-compute.html) describes a 1500+ decentralized cluster intercommunicating randomly. What is the outline of this process?

Answer (score 2):

It would be quite long to explain how Akka cluster works in detail, but I can try to give an overview.

The membership set in Akka is esentially a highly specialized CRDT. Since talking about Vector Clocks itself would be a lengthy discussion, I will use the analogy of git-like repositories.

You can imagine every Akka node maintaining its own repository where HEAD points to the current state of the cluster (known by that node). When a node introduces a change, it branches off, and starts to propagate the change to other nodes (this part is what is more or less random).

There are certain changes which we call *monotonic* which in the git analogy would mean that the branch is trivially mergeable. Those changes are just merged by other nodes as they receive them and they will then propagate the merge commit to others and eventually everything stabilizes (HEAD points to the same content).

There are other kind of changes that are not trivial to merge (*non-monotonic*). The process then is that a node first sends around a *proposal*: "I want to make this non-trivial change C". This is needed because the other nodes need to be aware of this pending "complex" change and prepare themselves. This is disseminated among the nodes until everyone receives it. Now we are at the state where "Everyone knows that someone proposed to make the change C", but this is not enough, since no one is actually aware that there is an agreement yet.

Therefore there is another "round", where nodes start to propagate the information "I, node Y, are aware of the fact that change C has been proposed". Eventually one or more nodes become aware that there is an agreement (this is more or less a distributed acknowledgement protocol). So the state now is "At least one node knows that every node knows that the change C has been proposed". This is (partly) what we refer to as *convergence*. At this point the node (or nodes) that are aware of the agreement will make the merge and propagate it.

Please note that I highly simplified the explanation here, obviously the devil (and scaling) is in the details :)

Comment: How do the nodes become aware of other nodes in a decentralized environment? I presume they have to be aware of the nodes they are communicating with. In a centralized environment, I would imagine nodes querying the "center" for a random node "address", which it in turn uses to send a message. How does this happen in a decentralized cluster?

Comment: Seed nodes + gossip.  Please read http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/common/cluster.html.